# grails message as argument of other message

Tags: grails, internationalization, taglib

I have this for example in my i18n messages_es.properties

```
birds.label=Aves
mammals.label=mamiferos
reptiles.label=reptiles

default.no.items.found=No se encontraron {0}
```

And then I want to use the message, inside the template argument in my Grails .gsp Views:

```
<g:message code="default.no.items.found" args="<g:message code='birds.label'/>"/>
```

This of course doesn't work. But is there a way to make this simple? Avoid overriding the "no found message" or defining an extra variable.

Comment: Have you tried this?: `<g:message code="whatever" args="${message(code: 'somethingelse')}" />`

Comment: No I had not tried that, and it works thanks. I supposed it was something simple as that but couldn't nailed it. Grails doc is quite poor.

Comment: Actually the Grails documentation is great for documenting the framework itself, but I do agree there is a learning curve when it comes to filling in some of the details about the underlying technologies. Glad you got it sorted out (might be helpful to accept the answer to this question for future users).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to your issue is quite simple. You're trying to call a nested tag library from another but you're not quite doing it right:

`<g:message code="whatever" args="${message(code: 'somethingelse')}" />`

Doing this should solve your issue.

Comment: I find I have to make `args` a list, otherwise `args` is a string and only the 0th character of the inner message makes it into the outer message.  i.e. `args="${[message(code: 'somethingelse')]}"`